# Jquery fadeIn not working first time around in FF. Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Issue: When page runs in FF 3.6 the fadeIn doesn't show, until after you've cycled through the galleries, then it works. How can I fix this?

Jquery Code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#gallerylinks a").each(function(index){
        $(this).click(function(){
          $(".gallerymain").hide();
          $("#gal"+index).fadeIn();
        });
      });
    });
```

HTML Code

```
<table width="960" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="gallerylinks">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="images/somename1.jpg" width="240" height="186" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="images/somename2.jpg" width="240" height="186" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="images/somename3.jpg" width="240" height="186" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="images/somename4.jpg" width="240" height="186" /></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fade won't work correctly because the images aren't loaded the first round, instead of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Do this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

The difference is that `window.onload` waits for images to be loaded, so they'll be there before the code runs...even the first time :)

Alternatively, you can pre-load the images when loading the gallery, there are [many](http://farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/) [options](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript) [out](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/preload-images-with-jquery.html) [there](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/) for this.

Comment: @vendy-dah-vindow-viper - Welcome :) If an answer resolved your issue be sure to mark it as accepted via the check-mark on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#gallerylinks a').click(function(){
    $(".gallerymain").hide();
    $("#gal"+index).fadeIn('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: There aren't any direct children like this, a `<table>` can't have any `<a>` children...so this wouldn't bind to any elements :)

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I updated the code and removed the ">" the child selector.  There's no need in the additional performance hit for the loop in the source above.